# how to register new helper (custom helper ) in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-studio, zend-view

i have used $view->addHelperPath and registerHelper what i want is when i go to view scripts files and do this $this->[myhlper method] get the data from my helper class ! i tried to set the path in the application.ini but that dosn't work either,so how to do it ?

Answer (score 2):

in your Bootstrap, add this method :

```
protected function _initView()
{
        $view = $this->bootstrap('layout')->getResource('layout')->getView();
        $view->addHelperPath('Your/Custom/Path/', 'Your_Custom_Path');

        $viewRenderer = new Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer();
        $viewRenderer->setView($view);

        Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper($viewRenderer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this `addHelperPath` call in bootstrap, like [me](https://github.com/azat/socialNetwork/blob/master/application/Bootstrap.php)