# What is the right way to register a custom helper in Zend Framework 1?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-view

I am working in a ZF 1.12.x project and I am adding a new custom helper stored at: `/application/views/helpers/MyFormText.php` (also tried with name `View_Helper_MyFormText`):

The content of the helper so far is simple as:

```
class MyFormText extends Zend_View_Helper_FormText
{
    public function MyFormText($name, $value = null, $attribs = null)
    {
        // @TODO: check if the component can be rendered on the view
        return parent::formText($name, $value, $attribs);
    }
}
```

As soon as I access the page I end with this error:

> [message:protected] => Plugin by name 'MyFormText' was not found in
>   the registry; used paths: Zend_View_Helper_:
>   Zend/View/Helper/:./../application/views/helpers/

Is weird that apparently this path:

```
 Zend_View_Helper_: Zend/View/Helper/:./../application/views/helpers/
```

Is used for look the helpers but even though the class can't be loaded. I have read and tried all of these:

- [Zend Framework Create Custom View Helper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10776868/zend-framework-create-custom-view-helper)
- [How to add a view helper directory (zend framework)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335545/how-to-add-a-view-helper-directory-zend-framework)
- [how to register new helper (custom helper ) in zend framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6358483/how-to-register-new-helper-custom-helper-in-zend-framework)
- [Zend: Where/how can I register custom view helpers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194716/zend-where-how-can-i-register-custom-view-helpers)

What I am doing wrong? Can any give me some help on this? I am stuck

Comment: Try printing the helper path/s.  From a view, you can var_dump($this).  You can register paths using `Zend_View::addHelperPath`.

Comment: @Progrock I am not seeing the path loaded so maybe isn't registered. Although I can see it on the error `Zend_View_Helper_: Zend/View/Helper/:./../application/views/helpers/`. Can you write a small example for me?

Comment: In application.ini -> `resources.view.helperPath.Your_View_Helper_Class_Prefix = APPLICATION_PATH "/views/helpers"`

Comment: @Progrock thanks for your time, I have found the answer and reply myself

Comment: Your view helper normally extends `Zend_View_Helper_Abstract`, and your name might be something like: `ReynierPM_MyFormText`.

Answer (score 0):

I have found my answer [here](https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html).

> By default, the class is prefixed with 'Zend_View_Helper_' (you can
>   specify a custom prefix when setting a helper path), and the last
>   segment of the class name is the helper name; this segment should be
>   TitleCapped; the full class name is then: Zend_View_Helper_FooBar.
>   This class should contain at the minimum a single method, named after
>   the helper, and camelCased: fooBar().

So by changing the class name from `MyFormText` to `Zend_View_Helper_MyFormText` make it to works.